# How can I check if npm packages support Node.js v0.8.x?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a deployed version 0.6 of Node.js with a considerable number of packages installed for various projects.

Is there a straight-forward way to check all of the packages that were installed using NPM to see if they support Node.js v 0.8.x?

I can see that the package.json files *should* say what version of Node they are for though I'm guessing that many will not include this - so I'm really only interested in packages that say they are definately **not** compatible with Node v 0.8.x

e.g. They have something like this in package.json:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "<0.8.0"
},
```

or

```
"engines": {
  "node": "=0.6.*"
},
```

I just want a simple list of packages that are incompatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in the base directory of your application:

```bsh
find . -name package.json -exec node -e 'var e = JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync(process.argv[1]))["engines"]; if (e && e.node) { var bad = false; if (e.node.match(/<\s*0\.[0-8]([^.]|\.0)/)) bad = true; if (e.node.match(/(^|[^>])=\s*0\.[^8]/)) bad = true; if (bad) console.log(process.argv[1], "appears no good (", e.node, ")") }' '{}' \;
```

Translation into normal style:

```js
var fs = require("fs");

var contents = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[1]);
var package = JSON.parse(contents);
var engines = package.engines;

if (engines && engines.node) {
    var node = engines.node,
        bad = false;

    if (node.match(/<\s*0\.[0-8]([^.]|\.0)/)) {
        // Looks like "< 0.8.0" or "< 0.8" (but not "< 0.8.1").
        bad = true;
    }

    if (node.match(/(^|[^>])=\s*0\.[^8]/)) {
        // Looks like "= 0.7" or "= 0.9" (but not ">= 0.6").
        bad = true;
    }

    if (bad) {
        console.log(process.argv[1], "appears no good (", node, ")");
    }
}
```

We then use `find` to run this on every `package.json` we can find.

Here's what I get when I run it over my [express-template.coffee](https://github.com/unnali/express-template.coffee) package:

```
./node_modules/jade/node_modules/commander/package.json appears no good ( >= 0.4.x < 0.8.0 )
./node_modules/mocha/node_modules/commander/package.json appears no good ( >= 0.4.x < 0.8.0 )
./node_modules/mocha/package.json appears no good ( >= 0.4.x < 0.8.0 )
```

It seems [TJ](http://github.com/visionmedia) has a thing against 0.8 ;-)

Comment: That wouldn't match <0.6 I think

Comment: OK, good start. And +1 for using Node to search Node. It is, however, a little specific - but you've got me on to something that I can work with thanks. I'll give it a little longer to see if anyone can come up with a generic solution.  On one of my deployments Jade and Commander fail. Not good. I think it will be a while before I can upgrade. (Oops, realised that you had the same packages fail!)

Comment: Of course, it is just commander. It is embedded into both Jade and Socket.IO  Though I checked a few other packeges manually and many of them either don't specify a Node version - dangerous given the amount of change it is going through - or they just say "*" - ugh!

Comment: As for TJ, perhaps he is playing safe - a good thing in my opinion.

Comment: @seppo0010: you're right. We'd probably want to change the `< 0.8` check to `< 0.[0-8]`-alike. (will change.)

Comment: @JulianKnight: I don't disagree that playing it safe is a good thing. 0.8 does have some oddities with the newer V8.

Answer (score 2):

`npm view <packageName> engines`

See the **npm view** [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-view) for more info.

For example:

`npm view jest verson` returns the latest version, in my case 27.1.0
`npm view jest engines` gives you:

```
{ node: '^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0' }
```

Which tells you the latest version of jest, v27, supports node 10.13, 12.13, 14.15, and 15.

`npm view jest@25 engines` however, tells you it supports anything over node 8.3:

```
jest@25.5.2 { node: '>= 8.3' }
jest@25.5.3 { node: '>= 8.3' }
jest@25.5.4 { node: '>= 8.3' }
```

(this response is to an old question, but it still come up on my Google search)